# How to set different style.css for different stores?

Tags: magento-1.9, css, store-view

I have **2 stores** in my website, I want to use different `CSS` for each store.

for now, same `css` file is used for both store but I want to use different CSS **for the store specific**

Comment: Are both your stores using the same theme?

Comment: yes, theme is the same for both store.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great run-through on themes that can be found [on Inchoo.net](http://inchoo.net/magento/creating-a-new-magento-theme/), and it seems that you just need to set up a separate fallback for each store.  For example, in `System->Configuration->Design->Themes`, you might have something like this:

[image]

In the `Current Configuration Scope` dropdown at the top of the left column, you should see a structure like this:

```
Default Config
  -- MyWebsite
    -- Store1
    -- Store2
```

If you have the default set and want to change it for `Store2`, then select it in the dropdown, and you can change the `Skin (Images/CSS)` to `storetwo`, for example.  Then, all you need to do is copy the desired files from `skin/frontend/base/default` to `skin/frontend/base/storetwo` and make your edits.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible,

1. go to `admin->system->configuration->general->design->themes->`Select your **store1** in top left corner of the admin page then put your `style1.css` in skin(image, css)->save, do the same operation for the **store2**.
2. create your two css `style1.css` and `style2.css` in go to `skin/frontend/{package}/{theme}/css/`
3. Clear your cache, now Magento get the configured css for each store.